# Lite/Pro version vs In-app-billing upgrade option

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have free version with limited functionalities&ads and paid ver. with full features with no ads.

I'm wondering, Should I make different ver. of app paid/free and upload it to market or
Lite version and **IN-APP-PURCHASE** to upgrade to pro version?

What should be the best choice in this case?
if you can give insights of pros and cons of IAP and pro/lite method would be great.

1Q:
if user installs free ver.  > makes in-app-purchase > uninstall

If he downloads it again then will he clicks in-app-purchase. Will Market ask him for money again (since he already paid?

ref:
[IAP android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099304/using-in-app-billing-to-purchase-full-version-of-the-game)

Answer (score 2):

Not really a programming question, the best choice depends on many things. In short, IAB is a bit harder to integrate, but may provide a better user experience: no need to install a separate app, and uninstall the free one later, etc. Maybe you should read the IAB [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) first to get an idea how it works.

As for your question, if you use a managed item, the purchase is tied to the user's Google account, so they will get the upgrade after moving to a new device for free (you need to restore transactions on first run to ensure this happens).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a license key like DocumentsToGo. The user has to download a 2nd app but you can even set it so it doesn't show up in the app drawer, basically the user wouldn't really notice that he DLs another app.

Comment: A possible benefit of this is the added exposure in Play Store (or wherever you put it).