# How to implement In App Upgrade for a Utility App in Android

Tags: android

I have just completed my App and realized that the path to moneytization I have in mind is not that straight forward to implement. This is a Customer Relationship Management app and I want users to be able to download to try it with up to 10 Customers. And then to purchase an upgrade to allow them to manage more than 10 customers.

I have followed the Android IAP official tutorial and I added the IAP library successfully and uploaded my APK and I am at the stage where it is asking to create a Product. What should my product be, all I want is to limit trial users to 10 rows in the Customer database. And paid users to unlimited rows.

Is this Use Case feasible with IAB? if yes, can you give me some pointers on how this can be implemented if no should I create two versions of the App one Lite and one Full version.

Thanks for you contribution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using In-App billing to purchase full version of the game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099304/using-in-app-billing-to-purchase-full-version-of-the-game)

Comment: Not quite, the question you reference is a game, mine is an Utility app and not a game.

Comment: I don't see how the fact that it is a game is relevant?

Comment: The game is using advertisement, my app does not use advertisement. The only difference is the number of rows in the database and my question how can I limit free app to 10 rows in local SQLITE database and paid customers to unlimited rows. Thanks

Comment: you are mixing 2 things. one thing is to implement the feature restriction in your app. one other thing is to use IAP to enable/disable this restriction. The link I suggested deals with the second part. The first part is up to you, and your question is about this part, it is way too broad.

Comment: Well that is actually the answer/clarification I need. Thank you

Comment: so, the question is actually `How do I limit the database table to a maximum of 10 rows`?

Comment: Yes, that is what the question should have been. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you ask a different question, and that you try to focus your question on that specific point. Include what you already have (database setup, ...) and what you have tried.